# PHP include ability in WP post/pages via shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a few `.html` and `.php` pages in my custom wordpress plugin directory/files that I'm using to output styles JSON/jQuery data basically.

I am wondering how I could essentially wrap these modules in a short code and insert that short code in my Wordpress posts or pages via the Wordpress wysiwyg editor. i.e. `[module 1]`. I do not want to do this in the theme's files or /`functions.php` I want to add this functionality from my plugin files, any thoughts?

---

So, like a php include in the form of a wordpress short code, that works in Wordpress pages.

---

**Here is what I'm trying; within my main plugin php file:**

---

```
function my_form_shortcode() {
    include dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'https://absolute.path.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-v4/assets/files/2019/results/index.php';
} 
add_shortcode( 'my_form_shortcode', 'my_form_shortcode' );
```

Within my Wordpress page, I do: *(although, does not display/work)*

```
[my_form_shortcode]
```

Comment: You need to put your content in that short code function so when you call that short code all the content will be displayed accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your shortcode function the same way you would in your theme

[add shortcode function in plugin](https://search.lilo.org/searchweb.php?q=add%20shortcode%20function%20in%20plugin&page=1)

Comment: It is a link for a Lilo Search to find the shortcode function as given by @Pawan Thakur

Answer (score -1):

Simplest example of a shortcode tag using the API: [footag foo="bar"]

```
function footag_func( $atts ) {
    return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'footag', 'footag_func' );
```

Example with nice attribute defaults: [bartag foo="bar"]

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'no foo',
        'baz' => 'default baz'
    ), $atts, 'bartag' );

    return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}
add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

Example with enclosed content: [baztag]content[/baztag]

```
function baztag_func( $atts, $content = "" ) {
    return "content = $content";
}
add_shortcode( 'baztag', 'baztag_func' );
```

If your plugin is designed as a class write as follows:

```
class MyPlugin {
    public static function baztag_func( $atts, $content = "" ) {
        return "content = $content";
    }
 }
 add_shortcode( 'baztag', array( 'MyPlugin', 'baztag_func' ) );
```

Comment: You evaded the question! I've update the question with more specific. I don't want to create a simply plugin that prints foo bar as provided by codex.

Comment: this link is not working for me 
https://absolute.path.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-v4/assets/files/2019/results/index.php